# Automatic run function for ever c# Quartz.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, quartz.net

I use Quartz.net in website for run job forever, and i want run job Automatically in server in every 15 min.

My problem is, User must visit site until application start in global.asax run and it works when user is in site, I want run job without visiting site and start it for ever without users be in site

I am using this code for running job in global.asax

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    SchedulerDemo.Interfaces.ISchedule myTask = new SchedulerDemo.Jobs.HelloSchedule();
    myTask.Run();
}
```

Comment: Where are you hosting your website? Do you have control on the server that is hosting it? Why do you want to run it (the task) from the website? Can't you use a [Windows Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service) or the [Windows Task Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler)?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with Quartz, but [these](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/deployment-to-production/making-aspnet-app-always-running.html) are the directions for Hangfire, which is similar to Quartz. A lot of the directions may be similar.

Comment: @YacoubMassad is correct. There is no reason for you to be doing this is web application code. This needs to be implemented so that it can be continually running on the server. As he mentions, use a windows service or windows task scheduler to run a console app.

Comment: If you want to run a task on regular intervals then use something like Windows Task Scheduler or cron.

Answer (score 1):

By default in Quartz.net, the jobs list and their trigger will be stored in memory, so as you have suspected, it will have to be defined in the Application_Start to be called on the first request.

You first need to get and start the scheduler in itself.

```
IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
scheduler.Start();
```

Then, still in your Application_Start method, you will have to define the job and it's trigger :

```
// Instantiating the job
IJobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.Create<MyJob>()
    .WithIdentity(new JobKey("MyVeryImportantJob", "VeryImportantJobGroup"))
    .Build();

ITrigger jobTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity(new TriggerKey("MyVeryImportantJobTrigger", "VeryImportantJobTriggerGroup"))
    .WithCronSchedule("* 0/15 * * * ?"") // execute every 15 min (in reality at HH:00, HH:15, HH:30 and HH:45)
    .Build();
```

And join the two to schedule the job

```
scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, jobTrigger);
```

The scheduler will then manage to call your job according to the trigger you defined (in  this case, every 15 min).

Also, as Quartz.Net will spawn a dedicated thread for the scheduler, it won't impact iis response process and it will prevent the iis worker to be recycled, so once it's launched, it will run forever until either the iis website or the host server is restarted.

After that, if you REALLY want your scheduler to start with the website without any request at all, you can use the Service Auto Start Provider (more info here :

https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2013/03/05/speeding-up-your-application-with-the-iis-auto-start-feature/

)